# Invalid value (400) using google translate api

Tags: google-api, google-translate, google-api-php-client

What's wrong with my request?

I have string in russian:
`$string = Потенциал, %`

I want to translate it to ukrainian with google API:

I urlencode string:

```
$q = urlencode($string)
```

And i request google API:

https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?q=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%2C%20%25&target=ua&source=ru&key=A...

In response I get :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

What's wrong with my request?

Comment: Your api key is invalid?

Comment: api key is fine, I just didn't post it here )

Comment: This error is encounterd when the target language code is invalid. By invalid means its not in the list of languages supported by Google translate API.

Answer (score 12):

Solution was simple. Google has **UK** letters for ukrainian instead of **UA**.

Comment: I had the same thing, but it was where I was using "kr" or Korea instead of "ka". (Which is a little nuts, because the Google Cloud Natural Language API uses "kr" for Korea and I just assumed the two APIs were standardized in their choice of two-letter country codes. THAT's something that should get fixed...)

Comment: Country codes are different from Language codes.  Korean language is "ko". 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes#Table_of_all_possible_two_letter_codes

Answer (score 3):

The target should be uk not ua.I think it will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was trying to translate to "es-uy" but despite being a valid [language code](https://www.andiamo.co.uk/resources/iso-language-codes/), Google doesn't support it.

Here are the language codes that the API supports:
https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages