# Google Translate API authentication [postman]

Tags: api, https, google-api, request, postman

I'm having an issue with Google Translate API (as many before me...). I need to run a test query via Postman to get a simple string translation. Nothing too fancy.

I'm trying to build the request based on the documentation but apparently I'm failing at the moment.

When using an API key, Google says I should simply add `key=MY_KEY` directly to the request string.

This is a similar issue to: [Why Google Translate API doesn't accept API-Key in JSON request body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043421/why-google-translate-api-doesnt-accept-api-key-in-json-request-body) But nobody has provided a good answer to that one (I'm also getting a different error)

My current example looks like this:

```
POST
https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2
?q=The Great Pyramid of Giza (also known as the Pyramid of Khufu or the Pyramid of Cheops) is the oldest and largest of the three pyramids in the Giza pyramid complex.
&source="en"
&target="es"
&format="text"
&key=MY_KEY_STRING
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting a 400: Invalid Value

```
{
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Invalid Value",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "invalid"
        }
    ]
}
```

Maybe somebody knows what the problem is? Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to send the request in the post body makes ure to tell postman that its content type json

```
POST https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=YourKey

{
  "key": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "q": "The Great Pyramid of Giza (also known as the Pyramid of Khufu or the Pyramid of Cheops) is the oldest and largest of the three pyramids in the Giza pyramid complex.",
  "source": "en",
  "target": "es",
  "format": "text"
}
```

Comment: You are correct (and I also found this 5 minutes after posting the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570649/invalid-value-400-using-google-translate-api)

MY ISSUE was that I was passing all params properly; however, in my POSTMAN request I added "test" instead of `text` (extra quotation marks).

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know I have to add key as param also